# Answering your own question

Tags: discussion, soft-question

Is it allowed to answer question you asked ?
When I press answer button, one of options is "Are you sure you want to answer your own question?"
I answered one of question I asked and got in trouble with people.
I'm just new here and want to play by the rules.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed, but this question should be asked on meta. Keep in mind that an answer should be complete and explain the issue (just as if you were answering someone else's question); I'm guessing that you're referring to the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582623/solving-01-3x-41-for-x), in which case it didn't really answer the question.

Comment: @ T. Bongers:  can you cite/link to a web page detailing the policies on answering one's own questions?  If you could, it would be most helpful.  Thanks, Bob Lewis

Comment: Answer for my question was very simple. So I also answered simple. I don't know what was a big deal about that ?

Comment: @ T. Bongers:  thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/18398

Comment: @Robert Lewis: there is no web page detailing any such policies. I think the consensus is that answering your own question is fine, in moderation, particularly when the user has discovered a complete answer based on comments before anyone else posted an answer. On the other hand, we have had issues with editor(s) posting numerous, idiosyncratic questions solely to answer them; there is not consensus in favor of that.

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to answer your own question. This is particularly encouraged if your question was resolved in back-and-forth comments but no actual answer was posted.

That you "got into trouble" after posting an answer could have something to do with the quality of the answer; I can't tell since  the answer was deleted.

And since you  *want to play by the rules*, I will add some suggestions: (i) proofread what you post; (ii) do not omit important information from a question and then casually add it in a comment, without editing the question.

Comment: I looked at the deleted answer, and the issue with it was that it was wildly incomplete. It just said that the answer to the question "is this correct" is that it was indeed correct; no explanation or reason was given.